# Appending data to a Spreadsheet if it is already not present

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am new to Google apps script and I am trying to write a program where whenever I scan a data. The scannedData should only be appended to the spreadsheet if and only if the data is not already present in the specific column (the First Column). I have written the following code but for some reason the data still gets appended even if it is present. If someone could please help me out, I would really appreciate that.

```
function insert(e,sheet) {
  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(range[i][0]!=scannedData) {
      sheet.appendRow([scannedData]);
       return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
    }
  } 
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Already Present !").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); 
}
```

Comment: PS : I also tried changing the getRange to point to the first column but the result is same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function insert(e,sheet) {
  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  if(!range.some(a => a === scannedData )){
      sheet.appendRow([scannedData]);
       return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
    }
  } else { 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Already Present !").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); 
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's necessary to replace `getDataRange()` by `getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow())` but it's very likely that this way is better.

`Array.prototype.some` "tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value".

Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some